# How can I clean up dreamhost vps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, vps, dreamhost

How can I cleap up everything in Dreamhost vps from SSH. I messed up everything so. I want to get it back as it was at first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used DreamHost VPS quite a bit and, similarly to the way that enterprise environments are structured, it's very helpful to have different shell accounts that have different roles. For example in one site that I maintain, we have a user under whose account the production application runs, one user for a staging instance, and another one with ftp privileges that allow admins to upload files.

In your case, it sounds like it might be best for you to create a new shell user with ssh access. You can then set up this user's environment as you require and switch the hosting for the domain you want over to this user. You'll be able to copy files from the old user's home directory as well so do this before you delete the original shell account.

You can create a new user in the DreamHost panel, under **Manage Users**. If you have a VPS account, then you'll be able to choose whether the user gets created on a shared host machine or your VPS machine.

You can choose which user account hosts a particular domain in the **Manage Domains** page. Click on **Edit** in the **Web Hosting** column beside the domain you want to change. Select your new VPS user in the **Run this domain under the user:** dropdown. Make sure that the **Web Directory:** field matches the folder structure you've set up in your user's home directory and you should be good to go.

You're allowed unlimited shell accounts on a DreamHost VPS so don't be afraid to use them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am foolish :D